# Pandas transform: creating two columns with function

Tags: python, pandas, transform, apply, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe df

```
df:

GROUP VALUE
 1     5
 2     2
 1     10
 2     20
 1     7
```

And a function

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

def z_score(x):
   z = np.abs(stats.zscore(x))
   c = np.where(x > 5, 1, 0)
   return z,c
```

And I am trying to create two columns in the dataframe with the help of function output and pandas transform method

```
df['zscore'], df['label'] = a.groupby(['GROUP'])['VALUE'].transform(z_score)
```

But getting the following error after running the above snippet

```
ValueError: Length of passed values is 2, index implies 3
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return `DataFrame` in function:

```
def z_score(x):
   z = np.abs(stats.zscore(x))
   c = np.where(x > 5, 1, 0)
   return pd.DataFrame({'zscore':z,'label':c}, index=x.index)

df[['zscore','label']] = df.groupby(['GROUP'])['VALUE'].apply(z_score)
print (df)
   GROUP  VALUE    zscore  label
0      1      5  1.135550      0
1      2      2  1.000000      0
2      1     10  1.297771      1
3      2     20  1.000000      1
4      1      7  0.162221      1
```

But for better performance is possible change code for `groupby` for `score` only and `label` column count after out of `groupby`:

```
def z_score(x):
   z = np.abs(stats.zscore(x))
   return z

df['zscore'] = df.groupby('GROUP')['VALUE'].transform(z_score)
#lambda function alternative
#df['zscore'] = df.groupby('GROUP')['VALUE'].transform(lambda x: np.abs(stats.zscore(x)))
df['label'] = np.where(df['VALUE'] > 5, 1, 0)
print (df)
   GROUP  VALUE    zscore  label
0      1      5  1.135550      0
1      2      2  1.000000      0
2      1     10  1.297771      1
3      2     20  1.000000      1
4      1      7  0.162221      1
```

Comment: @jezrael, sometime its difficult to visualize the operations after groupby and transform